# how to add both barchart and line graph in single chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Hi I am trying to attain both bar and line graph in one chart I was able to show bar graph(multiple vertical bars), need to show line graphs

```
 $("#chart1").html("");
 var xLabel = 'AREAS';
 var yLabel = 'NUMBERS';
 var yInterval='';
 var yInterval='';
  var S1 = [20, 60, 70, 100];
        var S2 = [70, 50, 30, 20];
        var S3 = [10, 50, 30, 20];
        var ticks = ['NA','APAC', 'EU','LATAM'];
        var yInterval=120;
        var count=120;

    $.jqplot('chart1', [S1, S2, S3], {
                            seriesColors:['#5882FA', '#DF7401', '#A4A4A4'],
                            seriesDefaults: {
                                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                                pointLabels: { show: true },
                                rendererOptions: {
                                        barWidth: 25,
                                        barDirection: 'vertical',
                                        barPadding: 0,
                                        fillToZero: true,
                                        shadowOffset: 0,
                                        shadowDepth: 0
                                    }
                            },
                            axes: {
                                xaxis: {
                                    label: xLabel,
                                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                    ticks: ticks
                                },
                                yaxis: {
                                  label: yLabel
                                }
                            },
                        });
```

I was trying to attain like the below chart

[image]

Comment: Go through the API documentation of jqplot. Please try to implement it and if you  face any problem then you can ask for specific problem.

Comment: hi @vinayakj I am facing issue in showing the line graph and the side panel where there % shown, I succeded in showing multiple vertical bars with data

Comment: See If [this](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/barLineAnimated.php) helps, not sure jQplot supports multiple graph formats in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define 2 additional series for your 2 line graphs:

```
 // Series for line graphs
 var S4 = [46, 38, 48, 47];
 var S5 = [33, 23, 38, 11];
```

And ensure these are passed in as parameters in addition to S1, S2 and S3:

```
$.jqplot('graph_stacked', [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5], {
```

Then add a `series` object that defines the renderers you want to use for each of the series. Here the first 3 use the [BarRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-barRenderer-js.html) and the last 2 use the [LineRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-lineRenderer-js.html):

```
series: [{
         label: 'Total Number of Distributors',
         renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer
     }, {
         label: 'Number of Distributors with at Least One Registered User',
         renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer
     }, {
         label: 'Number of Active Distributors',
         renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer
     }, {
         label: 'CMH Coverage %',
         renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer
     }, {
         label: 'Distributor Utilization Rate',
         renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer
     }]
```

Then add the additional colours for the 2 new line graphs:

```
seriesColors: ['#5882FA', '#DF7401', '#A4A4A4', '#ff00ff', '#00ffff'],
```

Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dy33ea54/15/) for a demo.

*Edit:* Update for the query regarding the y2axis:

Define a y2axis alongside the existing yaxis. Ensure the `showGridline` is set to false so it uses the same grid as the yaxis:

```
 y2axis:{
     label: y2Label,
     min:0,
     max:120,
     tickOptions:{showGridline:false}
 }
```

Then modify each `series` so they use the relevant yaxis renderer. In this case all the bar charts use the `yaxis` and the line charts use `y2axis`:

```
series: [{
    label: 'Total Number of Distributors',
    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    yaxis: 'yaxis'
 },
 ... 
 {
     label: 'Distributor Utilization Rate',
     renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,
     yaxis: 'y2axis'
}]
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dy33ea54/18/) for a demo.

Comment: hi @Ian A ,thanks a lot man for your effort and ya it matces what I need , only a small change required is the line renderer should be based on the value on y2axis, y2 axis should show values as of Y axis..can this be possible

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dy33ea54/18/)? Let me know if that's correct and I'll update my answer with an explanation

Comment: @lan Yes you got it, its the same

Comment: @Brittas I've edited my answer with an explanation of the y2axis query